# Out of Memory Issue when encode into base64 video file

Tags: android, file-upload, out-of-memory

I am trying to upload the video file into server with convert into base64. But I am getting out of memory exception even size is 2 mb also. How to resolve this issue. Please help me to over out, much appreciate your help.

Here what I am doing

```
  byte [] ba = convertByteArray(videoUri);
String baseimage=Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.NO_WRAP);

 public byte[] convertByteArray(Uri videoUri){

         InputStream iStream=null;
         byte[] inputData=null;
        try {
            iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(videoUri);
            inputData = getBytes(iStream);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return inputData;
     }

     public byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
          ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          int bufferSize = 1024;
          byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

          int len = 0;
          while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
          }
          return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
        }
```

Comment: if you want to upload large files to server please use multipart entity. That is the right way to upload large file to server. Otherwise you will get out of memory exception.

Comment: But i need to upload via base64, how to do ?

Answer (score -1):

Code :

```
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "rn";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
    String responseFromServer = "";
    String urlString = "http://your_website.com/upload_audio_test/upload_audio.php";
    try
    {
     //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
     URL url = new URL(urlString);
     // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
     conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     // Allow Inputs
     conn.setDoInput(true);
     // Allow Outputs
     conn.setDoOutput(true);
     // Don't use a cached copy.
     conn.setUseCaches(false);
     // Use a post method.
     conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
     dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
     dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
     dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile";filename="" + selectedPath + """ + lineEnd);
     dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
     // create a buffer of maximum size
     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
     buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
     // read file and write it into form...
     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
     while (bytesRead > 0)
     {
      dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
      bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
      bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
      bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
     }
     // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
     dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
     dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
     // close streams
     Log.e("Debug","File is written");
     fileInputStream.close();
     dos.flush();
     dos.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
         Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
         Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }
    //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
          inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
          String str;

          while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
          {
               Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
          }
          inStream.close();

    }
    catch (IOException ioex){
         Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
  }
```

Go through the following Sample for more reference :

http://coderzheaven.com/2011/08/uploading-audio-video-or-image-files-from-android-to-server/

For uploading video to server see doFileUpload() method from the above url.